# How do I fix model_publisher problem when running localization module on autoware with lgsvl?

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running localization module on autoware, I run into a error stating that:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: model_publisher

Has anybody encountered this?

Running Ubuntu 16.04 Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327604/how-do-i-fix-model_publisher-problem-when-running-localization-module-on-autoware-with-lgsvl?/) by [hdossaji94](https://answers.ros.org/users/43853/hdossaji94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The model_publisher failed to load mesh.
So, please check the urdf and vehicle model .dae path.

---

Originally posted by [Masaya Kataoka](https://answers.ros.org/users/41502/masaya-kataoka/) with karma: 111 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hdossaji94](https://answers.ros.org/users/43853/hdossaji94/) on 2019-07-08**:
Am i supposed to add the vehicle urdf and dae files in the autoware settings when trying to launch?